# Django GCBV UpdateView AttributeError - type object 'QuerySet' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am stuck at this Point. I want a view that extends the User model with a ForeignKey named `UserPlanet(models.Model)` and some other views, that extends the UserPlanet Model by OneToOneField. My setup looks like listed below. If I try to reach the view by the url I get an

> AttributeError at /game/ 
>   type object 'QuerySet' has no attribute '_meta'

How do I solve this? Unfortunately I am missing an approach. Unfortunately, I can not find anything in the django documentation

> views.py:

```
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .models import UserPlanet, UserShips, UserDefense, UserBuildings


class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    context_object_name = 'planets'
    template_name = 'game/home.html'
    fields = ('name', 'planet_size', 'free_fields', 'max_temperature', 'min_temperature', 'planet_galaxy',
              'planet_system', 'planet_position')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user.userplanet_set.all()
```

> models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class UserPlanet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(default='Heimatplanet', max_length=40)
    planet_size = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=150)
    free_fields = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=150)
    max_temperature = models.SmallIntegerField(default=80)
    min_temperature = models.SmallIntegerField(default=-20)
    planet_galaxy = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    planet_system = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    planet_position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    def create_user_planet(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserPlanet.objects.create(user=instance)

class UserResources(models.Model):
    user_planet = models.OneToOneField(UserPlanet, related_name='user_resources', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    minerals = models.IntegerField(default=1000)    # Mineralien
    food = models.IntegerField(default=0)           # Nahrung
    energy = models.IntegerField(default=0)         # Energie
    physics = models.IntegerField(default=0)        # Physik-Forschungspunkte
    engineering = models.IntegerField(default=0)    # Ingenieur-Forschungspunkte
    society = models.IntegerField(default=0)        # Gesellschafts-Forschungspunkte

    @receiver(post_save, sender=UserPlanet)
    def create_user_resources(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserResources.objects.create(user_planet=instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

`UpdateView` is for editing a single object. The `get_object` method should return a single object, not a queryset.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a suitable view, if each user can have any number of objects of type UserPlanet?

Comment: If you are editing multiple objects then you want to use formsets. There aren’t any generic views in Django for formsets, but you could look at django-extra-views.